# Backbone.js Task App how should grouped view look like

Tags: backbone.js, view, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I am developing a task app in Backbone.js for **FUN** and one of feature is grouped view. Grouped view will display tasks that are grouped according to their done status. Currently i can construct the grouped object from the collection. Constructing the view has become trivial to me. Here is a snapshot of how i want the view to look like

```
Completed Tasks

- Water the Garden

- Clean my closet

Pending Tasks

- Watch Whose line is it anyway
```

the JSON after grouping is below

```
{
    "true": [{
        "Name": "Finished Demo",
        "Done": true,
        "id": "4b3d8d3d-637c-fd5d-034b-b275b5f00e05"
    }, {
        "Name": "This is a new task",
        "Done": true,
        "id": "db5b379f-6f96-346d-4945-baf2d5ac0c76"
    }, {
        "Name": "Clean the closet",
        "Done": true,
        "id": "3b5091e5-a8df-845b-3c6d-2185187eb456"
    }],
    "false": [{
        "Name": "Edited another new task",
        "Done": false,
        "id": "0ee399b2-8fd9-84f2-735e-902d09c625a1"
    }]
}
```

I can't think of how to construct a template for the UI based on grouped json above. Assuming i am using underscore.js [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for templating purpose.

- How should the template look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, `true` and `false` are  <strike>reserved</strike> keywords in Javascript. I suggest you don't use it as variable names.

```
<ul>
    <% if (finished) { %>
        <% _.each(finished, function (task) { %>
            <li id=<%= task.id %>>
                <%= task.Name %>
            <input type="checkbox" checked />
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    <% }; %>
    <% if (unfinished) { %>
        <% _.each(unfinished, function (task) { %>
            <li id=<%= task.id %>>
                <%= task.Name %>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    <% }; %>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theotheo/zJXW8/

Comment: that worked. I also do get `<error>
_.extend
_.clone
_.extend.toJSON
App.Tasks.View.AppView.Backbone.View.extend.GroupBy
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i`. when the previous view is removed. I do it with below code `view.undelegateevents();view.remove();`

Comment: Hmm… I think you should probably create a separate question for this issue. And could you please post some code that is relevant to it? What does `undelegateevents?` method do?

Comment: no problem. It was one of Zombie problem. I had a reference to View instance through window object even though it was cleared out.

Comment: I'd guess that `undelegateevents` is a misspelling of [`undelegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents).

Comment: @muistooshort Aha! I wonder how I didn't realize it. Anyway, it seems to me that the problem was solved. Deeptechtons, am I right?